# How can i include new line search in regex in sed

Tags: regex, linux, sed

Basically i have the text file where i want to replace the lines which are in multi lines

I am using this code

`sed -rn ':a;N;$!ba;s/if(.*):://gp' file.txt`

Basically i am putting all lines in memory and then searching for the pattern.

I want `(.*)` to match new lines as well but its not doing it. what i am doing wrong

EDIT

This is the file

```
<?php

if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])) {
    exit('This script cannot be run from the CLI. Run it from a browser.');
}

if (!in_array(@$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], array(
    '127.0.0.1',
    '::1',
))) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
    exit('This script is only accessible from localhost:: .');
}

require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/../app/SymfonyRequirements.php';
```

I want to delete stuff before `require_once and if(!in_array)`

reuire_once should not be used as match as it can differ in other files

output

```
<?php

if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])) {
    exit('This script cannot be run from the CLI. Run it from a browser.');
}

require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/../app/SymfonyRequirements.php';
```

Comment: So you're trying to remove text starting from `if` to `::`?

Comment: @devnull yes, i want to delete those lines. they can span across multiple lines

Comment: I assume that a line doesn't contain any text after `::` that you want to retain, and anything before `if`?

Comment: @devnull , no rest all i want to retain. i only want to delete stuff between `if and ::`

Comment: It might be better if you provide some sample inputs and expected matches in your question.

Comment: @devnull i have added the detail and file for what i want, you will get more idea

Comment: It'd be better if you also add the expected output to be more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 sed -rn ':a;N;$!ba;s/if(.){0,5}in_array.*?}//gp' file.txt
<?php

if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])) {
    exit('This script cannot be run from the CLI. Run it from a browser.');
}



require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/../app/SymfonyRequirements.php';
```

Comment: well that worked perfectly but i could not get it where iwas wrong. so .* does include newline as well?

Comment: This will delete everything from the match to the last `}` in the file. Also, sed does not cater for the non-greedy metacharacters ``*?` so the `?` has no effect.

Answer (score 2):

If there are no blank lines in the range of text you want to delete then you can use much simpler awk command like this:

```
> cat file.php
<?php

if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])) {
       exit('This script cannot be run from the CLI. Run it from a browser.');
}

if (!in_array(@$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], array(
       '127.0.0.1',
           '::1',
           ))) {
       header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
           exit('This script is only accessible from localhost:: .');
}
require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/../app/SymfonyRequirements.php';

> awk '{sub(/if *\( *!in_array.*require_once/, "require_once")}1' RS= file.php
```

#### OUTPUT

```
<?php
if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])) {
       exit('This script cannot be run from the CLI. Run it from a browser.');
}
require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/../app/SymfonyRequirements.php';
```

**UPDATE:** Here is a gnu-awk version that can work with blank lines also:

```
awk '{sub(/if *\( *!in_array.*/, "") }1' RS='\n\n' file
```

Comment: There can be blank lines as well

Comment: I told in question that `require_once` can not be taken for granted as it can change across files

Comment: Oh without `require_once` it was super easy, see update. But this is prone to same problems as sed.

Answer (score 1):

Using `GNU sed`, you could say:

```
sed -e '/./{H;$!d;}' -e 'x;/::/d' filename
```

[This makes use of the fact that you have newlines between code blocks.]

Explanation:

- `/./` matches lines that are not blank.
- `H` appends those to the hold buffer.
- `$!d` causes those to be printed only at the end.
- Once a blank line is encountered, the second part kicks in.
- `x` exchanges the hold buffer with the pattern space.
- `/::/d` If the pattern matches `::` it is deleted.

---

If that is not the case, you could say:

```
sed -e :a -e '/if/,/}/ {/}/!{ $!{N;ba};};/::/d;}' filename
```

Comment: i could not understood your solution. i can have blank lines between codes block

Comment: @user3113427 Did you even try either of the two?  Both work for your sample input.

Comment: @devnull, you r right, that worked but i don't understood it. The solution by Dhruv closely matches with what i was trying to do so.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/if\s*(\s*!in_array/,/}/{/}/!d;$!N;/\n.*\S/D;d}' file
```

This deletes all lines between `if ( !in_array` and the next `}`. If the line following the `}` is empty it deletes this also.